# Twain question: is it possible to scan just one document from feeder?

Tags: c#, twain

I am playing with the code from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/twaindotnet.aspx

I am having a problem because twain returns control only after all documents in feeder are scanned. This leads to high memory usage if I scan 20 or more documents.

I thought of scanning just one document at a time from the feeder and saving the image and calling the api again in a loop.

I am setting cap_xfercount to 1 but this does not seem to help:

```
    TwCapability cap = new TwCapability(TwCap.XferCount, 1);
    rc = DScap(appid, srcds, TwDG.Control, TwDAT.Capability, TwMSG.Set, cap);
```

What do I need to do to scan just one document from the feeder?
Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: You should check out http://code.google.com/p/twaindotnet/ too; its based off the codeproject code.

Answer (score 6):

I'm sorry that I'm not familiar with the twaindotnet project, but I do have a lot of experience with document scanning through TWAIN.

First a note: Not all document feeders can feed in single-page mode; some important scanner families always scan everything in the feeder once started. And, quite a few TWAIN drivers won't honor XFERCOUNT=1, no matter what the standard says.

If you try to solve the problem by forcing the scanner to scan "one page jobs", you will be limited to the (indeterminate) set of scanners that happen to support that.  The TWAIN standard just doesn't require this feature.  (But yes - CAP_AUTOSCAN=FALSE and XFERCOUNT=1 would be the combo to try.)

There is a better solution (time & patience permitting) - It sounds like what you want to do is process and dispose of each image as it arrives, instead of collecting them all in memory.  Figure out how to get your TWAIN library to hand you each image (or write it to a file) as it arrives instead of stacking them up in memory, and you'll have a solution that works with all document-feeding scanners.  And it will scan quite a bit faster with most scanners, too...

Answer (score 1):

This is a feeder issue. Have you tried setting the feeder enabled capability to false?

EDIT:

Looks like CAP_AUTOFEED is the way to go. According to the [TWAIN 2.0 specification](http://www.twain.org/docs/TWAIN_2_Spec.pdf):

CAP_AUTOFEED
Description
If TRUE, the Source will automatically feed the next page from the document feeder after the number of frames negotiated for capture from each page are acquired. CAP_FEEDERENABLED
must be TRUE to use this capability.
Application
Set the capability to TRUE to enable the Source’s automatic feed process, ***or FALSE to disable it.***
After the completion of each transfer, check TW_PENDINGXFERS. Count to determine if the
Source has more images to transfer. A -1 means there are more images to transfer but the exact
number is not known.
CAP_FEEDERLOADED indicates whether the Source’s feeder is loaded. (The automatic feed
process continues whenever this capability is TRUE.)

Comment: Yes, I did and it tries to scan from flatbed

Comment: I can't seem to turn caP-autofeed off, maybe this capability is not supported by the scanner?

I tried
         cap = new TwCapability(TwCap.CAP_AUTOFEED, 0);
        rc = DScap(appid, srcds, TwDG.Control, TwDAT.Capability, TwMSG.Set, cap);

rc contains 'failure'

Comment: Hmm. There are a lot of capabilities to try. CAP_AUTOSCAN = false could do it. If that doesn't work I'm afraid I'm fresh out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the cababilities is important, see this doc [www.twain.org/docs/CapOrderForWeb](http://www.twain.org/docs/CapOrderForWeb.PDF).

EDIT:

These are some code fragments from a solution

Setup the auto feed

```
capFeederEnabled = _twEntities.GetCapability(TwCap.FeederEnabled, (short)1);
TwRC rc = DScap(_applicationId, _sourceId, TwDG.Control, TwDAT.Capability, TwMSG.Set, capFeederEnabled);

TwCapability cap = _twEntities.GetCapability(TwCap.XferCount, 1);
rc = DScap(_applicationId, _sourceId, TwDG.Control, TwDAT.Capability, TwMSG.Set, cap);
```

and then when the when the Twain Window Message is sent

```
rc = DSixfer(_applicationId, _sourceId, TwDG.Image, TwDAT.ImageNativeXfer, TwMSG.Get, ref hbitmap);
rc = DSpxfer(_applicationId, _sourceId, TwDG.Control, TwDAT.PendingXfers, TwMSG.EndXfer, pxfr);
```

finally reset the scanner for the next document

```
rc = DSpxfer(_applicationId, _sourceId, TwDG.Control, TwDAT.PendingXfers, TwMSG.Reset, pxfr);
```