# python-twain library in duplex mode get separate image from each side

Tags: python, twain

I am trying to scan using python-twain library in duplex mode and get two images one from each side.

```
import twain
sm = twain.SourceManager(0)
ss = sm.OpenSource('Plustek MobileOffice D600')

ss.SetCapability( twain.CAP_DUPLEXENABLED, twain.TWTY_BOOL, True )
ss.RequestAcquire(0,0)
rv = ss.XferImageNatively()
if rv:
    (handle, count) = rv
    twain.DIBToBMFile(handle, 'image.bmp')
```

The code only get one image but with the library documentation provided at http://twainmodule.sourceforge.net/ , I don't see how to get take independently images from it. I know is possible because I could get in a demo from a close source library CLScan(http://www.commandlinescanning.com).

Any suggestions will be welcome.

Comment: Is it possible that the one image is overridden by the other?

Comment: I think it is not overridden. And variable 'count' is not increasing to 2 stay in 1. The problem documentation of library is very poor.

Comment: Yes, that's a trade-off of open source products. I recommend you check the following things: 1. Verify if the duplex mode is set successfully 2. You may need to set cap_xfercount. check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260357/twain-question-is-it-possible-to-scan-just-one-document-from-feeder) and see if it helps.

Comment: @Rachel: when i used the answer code, then the duplex mode is failing to set True. Please advise. we have to make this answer reliable. i have few TWAIN devices. all the other answers are confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the sample code [TwainBackend.py](https://github.com/albertca/NanScan/blob/master/NanScan/Backends/TwainBackend.py) on GitHub. You can use a loop to save all available images:

```
import twain

index = 0;

def next(ss):
    try:
        print ss.GetImageInfo()
        return True
    except:
        return False

def capture(ss):
    global index
    rv = ss.XferImageNatively()
    fileName = str(index) + '_image.bmp';
    index+=1;
    print rv;
    if rv:
        (handle, count) = rv
        twain.DIBToBMFile(handle, fileName) 

sm = twain.SourceManager(0)
ss = sm.OpenSource('Plustek MobileOffice D600')

try:    
    ss.SetCapability( twain.CAP_DUPLEXENABLED, twain.TWTY_BOOL, True)
except:
    print "Could not set duplex to True"

print "acquire image"
ss.RequestAcquire(0,0)

while next(ss):
    capture(ss)

print('Done')
```

Comment: NOT -working to print front and rear. nor even working to save more pages. Please can you update how to duplex scan rear and front please?

Comment: I tried `ss.set_capability(twain.CAP_DUPLEXENABLED, twain.TWTY_BOOL, True)` but still duplex not happening fails.